# IE 11 Crashes In Windows 10

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I'm experiencing an issue with a login page.  When the page loads the F12 Developer tools gives this error - SCRIPT1002 on FWi.js (1,1).  When I put in the login information and submit the tab crashes and reopens.  This is the script information from that file.

```
<script src="../../js/lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/lib/gibberish-aes-1.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
var encrypt = function(uobj, token) {
    var str = JSON.stringify(uobj);
    var encrypted = GibberishAES.enc(str, token);
    return escape(encrypted);
};


$(document).ready(function() {

   $("#submitButton").click(function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     var loginForm = document.getElementById("loginform");
     var un = $(loginForm).find('#user-name').val(),
     up = $(loginForm).find("#user-pass").val(),
     tok = $(loginForm).find("#ekey").val();

     var encrypted = encrypt({username:un, password: up, instanceType: "browser"}, tok);
     $("#user-name").remove();
     $("#user-pass").remove();

     var encup = $('<input type="hidden" name="authorization" value="Bearer ' + encrypted + '"/>');
     $(loginForm).append(encup);

     loginForm.submit();
  });
});
</script>
```

Any ideas what could be causing this issue?

Comment: You might want to post the code in the first line of `FWi.js`. Have you tested in other browsers to see if you can reproduce it? Chrome's developer tools tend to be more helpful than IE11's.

Comment: It works in Chrome.  This is purely an IE 11 issue where the page crashes and reopens the login screen after submitting credentials.